# Как разместить текст справа от элемента?

Tags: html, css

```
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 ">
                <div class="special__item">
                    <div class="circule">
                        <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                    </div>
                    <span class="special__item__title">
                            Разработка дизайна
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
    ***.circule {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #8e9cff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fafaff;
    font-size: 32px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(#8b62ff,#6299ff);
    text-align: left;
}

.circule i {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.special__item__title {
    color: #3c3f59;
    font-size: 18px;
     display: table-row;
}***
```

[image: хелп]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.circule {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: #8e9cff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fafaff;
  font-size: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(#8b62ff, #6299ff);
  text-align: left;
}

.circule i {
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

.special__item__title {
  color: #3c3f59;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: table-row;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.special__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 ">
    <div class="special__item">
      <div class="circule">
        <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
      </div>
      <span class="special__item__title">Разработка дизайна</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое